# Google plus Native plugin with webClientId

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, google-plus, ionic3

I'm using [**native Google Plus**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/) plugin with **Ionic 3** app.

`Login()` method is like this:

```
login(){

        GooglePlus.login({
          'webClientId': '*************************'
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }
```

The problem here is about the `webClientId`.Hence I have created 2 apps on developer console (iOS and Android), it shows 2 different `webClientId`s.So which value should I give to above code?

Comment: Do you want to get `idToken` or `serverAuthCode`? Or it just simple user authentication?

Comment: Don't delete the answer.I'll test that and will let you know.I'm waiting for my backend dev's feedback.After that, I'll give you a feedback.I think, your answer is the correct one for my simple use case. @SwapnilPatwa

Comment: Ok, i thought i missed `idToken` part and got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Helpful link:** [**Ionic Google Authentication**](https://javebratt.com/ionic-google-login/)

**Plugin link:** [**enter link description here**](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

You don't need to put webClientId in `GooglePlus.login()`.

Your login method should be (if no additional options)-

```
GooglePlus.login({}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**iOS**

You need to put `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` in `config.xml` for iOS.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.967272422526-vu37jlptokv45glo2kciu9o2rddm7gte" />
</plugin>
```

To find you `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`, in developer console go to credentials and click on created iOS credential and `Download Plist`.

[image]

**Android**

For android you don't need any id, it works on `Signing-certificate fingerprint`, make sure the `Signing-certificate fingerprint` and `Package name` are correct while creating `oauth client id`.

[image]

If you are not signing your apk with any created keystore file then take `SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint` of default debug.keystore file.

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\Username\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

I have used most common path of `debug.keystore` (windows). It might be different for you, just look for `.android` dir.

Comment: Actually, I need to set up for Android.You have mentioned for the iOS no?

Comment: Yes, that only.Do you know what this path is `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`.This path `~/.android/debug.keystore`?

Comment: OK.Hope I can use this command to test that on my android device no? After doing all above.  `ionic cordova run android --device`

Comment: It seems typo on your cmd no? '--prod'?

Comment: Nope, It will make your app much faster, specially during  start. try it.

Comment: Oh..Hope I cannot debug then no? Will it print `console.log()` messages?

Comment: You can. log will also work. --prod flag enable AoT/uglify.

Comment: Oh..Sorry I didn't get you `AoT/uglify`? What was that?

Comment: But for android, how we can store reversed REVERSED_CLIENT_ID ? without cordova cli ? in android manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Find your **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID** inside `GoogleService-Info.plist` from firebase.